# Removing only black text font on a large cell range

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I need: 
I have more than 20.000 cells containing in the same cell text in black and red
I want to delete all black text (maintaining red) contained in cells rage A1:A20347. But my routine won’t work. A little help will be appreciated

```
Sub deleteonlyblacktextincell()

Range("A1:A20347").Select    
        For Each Cell In Selection
        If Font.ColorIndex = 1 Then

        ' it is here where a want to delet only black text maintening other color text in the same cell

        End If
        Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have cells in which some of the text is red and some of the text is black??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent the note in the code states that `delet only black text maintening other color text in the same cell`

Comment: You will need to iterate through each character in each cell (So two loops) testing each character for the color and create a temp string of only those that are red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick out character colours and test them individually:

```
Sub deleteonlyblacktextincell()

    Range("A1:B20347").Select

    For Each cell In Selection
        Dim textOut As String
        textOut = ""
        For i = 1 To Len(cell)
            If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex <> 1 Then
                textOut = textOut & Mid(cell, i, 1)
            End If
        Next
        cell.Value = textOut
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok ,,, If Cell.Font.ColorIndex =1 Then ... here is my problem: deleting only the black text....

Comment: `If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex <> 1`  Op wants to remove the black text not keep it.

Comment: Very nice routine

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Sub deleteonlyblacktextincell()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection

For Each Cell In rng
    If Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 1 Then

    'this only removes the text and doesn't delete the Cell itself
    Cell.Value = ""

    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Almost there! The only problem are cells containing red and black text. In those cases both colors are maintained

Comment: I guess in this case your question is unclear. Do you just want to delete the black characters or the whole text in a Cell?

Comment: Thanks for your help... I want to keep only red text